# Redirect page after some time using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect the click a tell HTTP API using .htaccess file.

I need the system to stay on that api page to send a message and then redirect to another page after 10 sec. Here is what i found yet :

```
   RewriteRule ^mypage\.html$  /mypage2.html [R]
```

But i want to insert time here for page 1 to stay .

any suggestions ?

Comment: Use javascript for that

Comment: how ? i cant change anything in that API page.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with htaccess

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via a temporary file handler in your site root. Create a file called `timer.php` with this code:

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" 
              content="<?php echo $_GET['delay'];?>;URL=<?php echo $_GET['target'];?>">
</head>
</html>
```

Then have your rewrite as this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^mypage\.html$ timer.php?delay=10&target=/mypage2.html [L,NC]
```

This will redirect the `/mypage.html` to `/mypage2.html` after 10 seconds delay. If you want you can display some custom message/image for these 10 seconds.